# How to terminate a while loop when an Xpath query returns a null reference html agility pack

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to loop through every row of a **variable length** table on the a webpage (http://www.oddschecker.com/golf/the-masters/winner) and extract some data

The problem is I can't seem to catch the null reference and terminate the loop without it throwing an exception!

```
int i = 1;
bool test = string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(String.Format("//*[@id='t1']/tr[{0}]/td[3]/a[2]", i))[0].InnerText);

while (test != true)
{
    string name = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(String.Format("//*[@id='t1']/tr[{0}]/td[3]/a[2]", i))[0].InnerText;
    //extract data
    i++;
}
```

try-catch statements don't catch it either:

```
bool test = false;
try
{
     string golfersName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(String.Format("//*[@id='t1']/tr[{0}]/td[3]/a[2]", i))[0].InnerText;
 }
 catch
 {
      test = true;
 }

 while (test != true)
 {
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code logic is a bit off. With the original code, if  `test` evaluated `true` the loop will never terminates. It seems that you want to do checking in every loop iteration instead of only once at the beginning.

Anyway, there is a better way around. You can select all relevant nodes without specifying each `<tr>` indices, and use `foreach` to loop through the node set :

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='t1']/tr/td[3]/a[2]");
foreach(HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string name = node.InnerText;
    //extract data
}
```

or using `for` loop instead of `foreach`, if index of each node is necessary for the "extract data" process :

```
for(i=1; i<=nodes.Count; i++)
{
    //array index starts from 0, unlike XPath element index
    string name = nodes[i-1].InnerText;
    //extract data
}
```

**Side note :** To query single element you can use `SelectSingleNode("...")` instead of `SelectNodes("...")[0]`. Both methods return `null` if no nodes match XPath criteria, so you can do checking against the original value returned instead of against `InnerText` property to avoid exception :

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("...");
if(node != null)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Ah awesome, thank you! How's the weather in Jakarta? :)